# How marker of geolocate add to map?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I make a screen with a map on which had be the marker with my location and the marker of my choose coordinates on the map. How can i put a marker with my location on the map?

```
class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
var currentLocation;

  GoogleMapController mapController;
  _getLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();

      print("locationLatitude: ${currentLocation["latitude"]}");
      print("locationLongitude: ${currentLocation["longitude"]}");
      setState(
              () {
              mapController.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions(
                  position: LatLng(37.421971, -122.084056),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
                ),

              );
              mapController.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions(
                  position: LatLng(currentLocation["latitude"],currentLocation["longitude"]),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
                ),
              );});
    } on Exception {
       currentLocation = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
    options:GoogleMapOptions(
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
              ),
    );
  }
}
```

Marker with my selected coordinates appears but marker with my location dosen't.

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use location [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location#-example-tab-) to detect location which will provide you the lat long coordinates and you can add marker as you have in your code.